# Conexión Android Studio con base de datos en Xampp

Tags: php, android, webservice

He estado trabajando en una aplicación en `Android` para conectarme a una base de datos. El código que uso es este:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private EditText editnombre, editApellido;
     private Button btnConectar;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editnombre = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editNombre );
        editApellido = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editApellido);
        btnConectar = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnConectar );
        btnConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ejecutarServicio( "http://192.168.1.106:8080/pruebaDBandroid/insertar_datos.php" );
        }
    });
}
public void ejecutarServicio(String url){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operacion exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError{
            Map<String, String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("nombre", editnombre.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("apellido", editApellido.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

He agregado también la librería para hacer las peticiones al web service:

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
```

Así como los permisos para el Internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Cuando ejecuto el código recibo el mensaje **"operación exitosa"** que he colocado dentro del método `ejecutarServicio`, lo que me indica que la aplicación esta funcionando, pero por alguna razón cuando entro al `localhost` veo mi base de datos, no tengo ningún dato nuevo, no se agregan los valores. ¿Qué podría estar mal?

Estos son mis archivos php:

**insertar_datos.php:**

```
<?php

    include 'conexion.php';
    $nombre=$_POST['nombre'];
    $apellido=$_POST['apellido'];

    $consulta = "INSERT INTO data VALUES('".$nombre."', '".$apellido."')";
    mysqli_query( $conexion,$consulta ) or die( mysqli_error() );
    mysqli_close( $conexion );
?>
```

**conexion.php:**

```
<?php
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $database = 'db1';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '1234';
    $conexion = new mysqli( $hostname, $username, $password,$database );
    if($conexion->connect_errno){
        echo "Lo sentimos, el sitio web esta experimentando problemas"
    }
?>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. En mi caso, para obtener los datos que paso por medio de `Volley` tengo que recuperarlos usando `apache_request_headers()`. Intenta hacerlo así: `$mPost=apache_request_headers();` y luego: `$nombre=$mPost['NOMBRE'];  $apellido=$mPos['APELLIDO'];`, Lo pongo en mayúsculas porque recuerdo que aunque pasase las claves en minúscula, en el servidor las recibía en mayúscula y si usaba minúsculas no me encontraba los datos. Si aún así no funciona, haza un `var_dump($mPost);` una vez creado con `apache_request_headers()` y dinos lo que imprime.

Answer (score 0):

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

En mi caso era imposible encontrar los valores pasados desde Android al servidor usando `$_POST`.

La única forma en que he podido recuperar los datos ha sido pasándolos mediante el método `getHeaders` y en el servidor recuperándo los encabezados con `apache_request_headers()`.

Una particularidad es que `apache_request_headers()` convierte la primera letra de cada clave en mayúscula. Para la coherencia entonces puedes ponerlo ya así en Android para evitar confusiones.

El código sería:

### Android

```
        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() {
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("Nombre", "Pedro");
            headers.put("Apellido", "García");
            return headers;
        }
```

---

### PHP

Me voy a permitir mejorar varias cosas de tu código PHP. Por ejemplo, en el archivo que recibe los datos es preciso que controles el flujo, recogiendo siempre un texto que al menos informa al usuario de lo que ha ocurrido.

No puedes escribir un código que en ciertas situaciones no diga nada. El resultado para el cliente será una pantalla en blanco, sin que éste sepa qué ha fallado.

---

#### `insertar_datos.php`

---

```
<?php 
    $_POST=apache_request_headers();
    /* Solamente para prueba ---------------------------------*/
       var_dump($mPost);
    /* ------------------------------------------------------*/
    $nombre   =!empty($_POST['Nombre'])   ? $_POST['Nombre']   : NULL;
    $apellido =!empty($_POST['Apellido']) ? $_POST['Apellido'] : NULL;
    if ($nombre && $apellido) {
        include 'conexion.php';
        if($conexion){
            /*
                Apunto varias cosas aquí, pues veo que apliquas malas prácticas:
                    1. Seguridad por favor, usa consultas preparadas (leer sobre Inyección SQL)
                    2. Acostumbra a nombrar cada columna en el INSERT, 
                       en un futuro la tabla puede incorporar
                       nuevas columnas y un INSERT no explícito podría crear un lío. 
                       Cambia en el código aquiColumnaNombre y aquiColumnaApellido por los nombres reales
                    3. Usaremos el estilo orientado a objetos, es mucho más claro y de hecho lo usas en la conexión
            */
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO data (aquiColumnaNombre, aquiColumnaApellido) VALUES(?,?)";
            if ( $stmt=$conexion->prepare($consulta) ){
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nombre,$apellido);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $txtOut="Filas insertadas: ".$conexion->affected_rows;
                    $conexion=NULL;
            } else {
                $txtOut="Error: ".$conexion->error;        
            }
        } else {
            $txtOut="La conexión es nula";
        }
    } else {
        $txtOut="No se postearon datos";    
    }
    echo $txtOut;
?>
```

---

#### `conexion.php`

---

Evita sacar información por pantalla. Puede que necesites este código en un futuro para obtener datos y presentarlos como un JSON. El `echo` ahí te podría fastidiar el bloque de error que incluirías en el JSON.

Aquí simplemente controla la conexión y cuando haya error, la seteas a `NULL`.

He puesto también el juego de caracteres utf8. Conviene ponerlo para no tener problemas con las tildes y caracteres raros.

```
<?php 
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $database = 'db1';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '1234';
    $conexion = new mysqli( $hostname, $username, $password,$database );
    $conexion->set_charset("utf8");
    if($conexion->connect_errno){
        $conexion=NULL;
    }   
?>
```

### PD

Si el código te dice que no se postearon datos, prueba lo que hay en `$mPost` mediante:

```
var_dump($mPost);
```

En mi caso los datos se muestran correctamente:

```
array(8) 
        {
          ["Content-Length"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["Content-Type"]=>
          string(25) "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
          ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
          string(4) "gzip"
          ["Apellido"]=>
          string(7) "García"
          ["Host"]=>
          string(17) "www.example.com"
          ["Nombre"]=>
          string(5) "Pedro"
          ["User-Agent"]=>
          string(69) "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; Redmi 3 MIUI/V9.6.2.0.LAIMIFD)"
          ["X-Forwarded-For"]=>
          string(14) "XX.YYY.ZZZ.150"
        }
```

---

En Android, puedes agregar el resultado de response al Toast, así ves lo que ocurrió:

```
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operacion exitosa"+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: Antes que nada, agradezco tu bienvenida a este espacio. De igual forma, agradezco tus comentarios sobre consultas PHP. Soy electrónico y nunca he programado estos lenguajes para base de datos, por lo que pido una disculpa por la mala práctica. He realizado los cambios que me has echo en los tres archivos pero sigo sin poder ver los datos agregados a la base de datos. 
Donde ejecuto la instrucció var_dump($mPost); para ver los datos?

Comment: @Marcelino En `insertar_datos.php` puedes ejecutarla, después de crear la variable con `apache_request_headers()`, (revisa la respuesta editada). Observa también al final de la respuesta, puse el texto de la respuesta del servidor en el Toast, para que muestre el texto recogido en el servidor. Dinos qué mensaje imprime el Toast. Recuerda también poner los nombres de columna correctos en la consulta SQL: `INSERT INTO data (aquiColumnaNombre, aquiColumnaApellido) VALUES(?,?)`