# Conexión MySQL Xampp con Android studio

Tags: android, base-de-datos, webservice

He estado realizando un código en `Android Studio` para conectarme a una base de datos local en ***Xampp***. Al ejecutar mi aplicación me dice que la operación se ha realizado pero al entrar a mi `localhost` y revisar mi base de datos, no tengo ningún valor agregado. ¿Qué puede ser?

El código que uso en ***Android Studio*** es este:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editnombre, editApellido;
    private Button btnConectar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        editnombre = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editNombre );
        editApellido = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.editApellido);
        btnConectar = (Button) findViewById( R.id.btnConectar );
        btnConectar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ejecutarServicio( "http://192.168.1.106:8080/pruebaDBandroid/insertar_datos.php" );
            }
        });
    }
    public void ejecutarServicio(String url){
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operacion exitosa", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener(){
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            public Map getHeaders() {
                HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
                headers.put("Nombre", "Pedro");
                headers.put("Apellido", "García");
                return headers;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

He agregado el permiso para conexión a internet:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Me han ayudado con los archivos web services en `PHP`. Realmente no se si estén bien pero aquí les dejo los archivos para que los evalúen:

````
insertar_datos.php
```
<?php 
    $mPost=apache_request_headers();
    $nombre   =!empty($_POST['nombre'])   ? $_POST['nombre']   : NULL;
    $apellido =!empty($_POST['apellido']) ? $_POST['apellido'] : NULL;
    if ($nombre && $apellido) {
        include 'conexion.php';
        if($conexion){
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO data (nombre,apellido) VALUES(?,?)";
            if ( $stmt=$conexion->prepare($consulta) ){
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nombre,$apellido);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $txtOut="Filas insertadas: ".$conexion->affected_rows;
                    $conexion=NULL;
            } else {
                $txtOut="Error: ".$conexion->error;        
            }
        } else {
            $txtOut="La conexión es nula";
        }
    } else {
        $txtOut="No se postearon datos";    
    }
    echo $txtOut;
?>
```
conexion.php
```
<?php 
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $database = 'db1';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '1234';
    $conexion = new mysqli( $hostname, $username, $password,$database );
    $conexion->set_charset("utf8");
    if($conexion->connect_errno){
        $conexion=NULL;
    }   
?>
```
````

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92112/discussion-on-question-by-marcelino-conexion-mysql-xampp-con-android-studio).

Answer (score 2):

> Respuesta trasladada aquí desde [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/252259/29967) porque al parecer
>   el OP perdió el control de la otra cuenta.

Te doy la bienvenida a Stackoverflow.

En mi caso era imposible encontrar los valores pasados desde Android al servidor usando `$_POST`, como se hace por lo general mediante los formularios HTML. Estuve investigando el motivo sin encontrar nada al respecto<sup>1</sup>. Pero sí he encontrado una forma para recuperar los datos.

Se requieren dos cambios en el código:

- En Android, pasándolos mediante el método `getHeaders`
- En el servidor recuperando los encabezados con [`apache_request_headers()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.apache-request-headers.php).
  Una particularidad es que `apache_request_headers()` **convierte la primera letra de cada clave en mayúscula** (ver resultado del `var_dump` al final de esta respuesta). Para la coherencia entonces puedes ponerlo ya así en Android para evitar confusiones. Si lo pones todo en minúscula de todos modos `apache_request_headers()` pondrá la primera letra en mayúscula.

El código sería:

### Android

```
        @Override
        public Map getHeaders() {
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("Nombre", "Pedro");
            headers.put("Apellido", "García");
            return headers;
        }
```

---

### PHP

Me voy a permitir mejorar varias cosas de tu código PHP. Por ejemplo, en el archivo que recibe los datos es preciso que controles el flujo, recogiendo siempre un texto que al menos informa al usuario de lo que ha ocurrido.

No puedes escribir un código que en ciertas situaciones no diga nada. El resultado para el cliente será una pantalla en blanco, sin que éste sepa qué ha fallado.

---

#### `insertar_datos.php`

---

```
<?php 
    $mPOST=apache_request_headers();
    /* Solamente para prueba ---------------------------------*/
       var_dump($mPOST);
    /* ------------------------------------------------------*/
    $nombre   =!empty($mPOST['Nombre'])   ? $mPOST['Nombre']   : NULL;
    $apellido =!empty($mPOST['Apellido']) ? $mPOST['Apellido'] : NULL;
    if ($nombre && $apellido) {
        include 'conexion.php';
        if($conexion){
            /*
                Apunto varias cosas aquí, pues veo que apliquas malas prácticas:
                    1. Seguridad por favor, usa consultas preparadas (leer sobre Inyección SQL)
                    2. Acostumbra a nombrar cada columna en el INSERT, 
                       en un futuro la tabla puede incorporar
                       nuevas columnas y un INSERT no explícito podría crear un lío. 
                       Cambia en el código aquiColumnaNombre y aquiColumnaApellido por los nombres reales
                    3. Usaremos el estilo orientado a objetos, es mucho más claro y de hecho lo usas en la conexión
            */
            $consulta = "INSERT INTO data (aquiColumnaNombre, aquiColumnaApellido) VALUES(?,?)";
            if ( $stmt=$conexion->prepare($consulta) ){
                    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nombre,$apellido);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $txtOut="Filas insertadas: ".$conexion->affected_rows;
                    $conexion=NULL;
            } else {
                $txtOut="Error: ".$conexion->error;        
            }
        } else {
            $txtOut="La conexión es nula";
        }
    } else {
        $txtOut="No se postearon datos";    
    }
    echo $txtOut;
?>
```

---

#### `conexion.php`

---

Evita sacar información por pantalla. Puede que necesites este código en un futuro para obtener datos y presentarlos como un JSON. El `echo` ahí te podría fastidiar el bloque de error que incluirías en el JSON.

Aquí simplemente controla la conexión y cuando haya error, la seteas a `NULL`.

He puesto también el juego de caracteres utf8. Conviene ponerlo para no tener problemas con las tildes y caracteres raros.

```
<?php 
    $hostname = 'localhost';
    $database = 'db1';
    $username = 'root';
    $password = '1234';
    $conexion = new mysqli( $hostname, $username, $password,$database );
    $conexion->set_charset("utf8");
    if($conexion->connect_errno){
        $conexion=NULL;
    }   
?>
```

### PD

Si el código te dice que no se postearon datos, prueba lo que hay en `$mPost` mediante:

```
var_dump($mPost);
```

En mi caso los datos se muestran correctamente:

```
array(8) 
        {
          ["Content-Length"]=>
          string(1) "0"
          ["Content-Type"]=>
          string(25) "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
          ["Accept-Encoding"]=>
          string(4) "gzip"
          ["Apellido"]=>
          string(7) "García"
          ["Host"]=>
          string(17) "www.example.com"
          ["Nombre"]=>
          string(5) "Pedro"
          ["User-Agent"]=>
          string(69) "Dalvik/2.1.0 (Linux; U; Android 5.1.1; Redmi 3 MIUI/V9.6.2.0.LAIMIFD)"
          ["X-Forwarded-For"]=>
          string(14) "XX.YYY.ZZZ.150"
        }
```

---

En Android, puedes agregar el resultado de response al Toast, así ves lo que ocurrió:

```
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Operacion exitosa: \n"+response, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

---

1. Ver al respecto la pregunta: [¿Por qué cambia la primera letra a mayúscula en los encabezados enviados desde Android a servidor PHP mediante Volley?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/199626/29967), sin haber obtenido aún respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Tenia el mismo problema que tú, utilice esta inserción en php y funcionó.

```
<?php
$hostname='localhost';
$database='beta';
$username='root';
$password='';

$json=array();

if (isset($_GET["nombre"]) && isset($_GET["correo"])){
    $nombre=$_GET['nombre'];
    $correo=$_GET['correo'];

    $conn = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

    $insert="INSERT INTO users(nombre,correo) VALUES ('{$nombre}','{$correo}')";
    $resultado_insert=mysqli_query($conn,$insert);

    if($resultado_insert){
        $consulta="SELECT *FROM users WHERE nombre = '{$nombre}'";
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conn,$consulta);

        if($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            $json['users'][]=$registro;
        }
        mysqli_close($conn);
        echo json_encode($json);
    }
    else{
        $resulta["nombre"]='No Registra';
        $resulta["correo"]='No Registra';
        $json['users'][]=$resulta;
        echo json_encode($json);
    }

}
else{
    $resulta["nombre"]='No Retorna';
    $resulta["correo"]='No Retorna';
    $json['users'][]=$resulta;
    echo json_encode($json);

}

?>
```

además en el main activity, cambia la función de inserción de datos y lo hice directamente en la url

```
BotonAgregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CargarWebServices();

            }


        });
    }

    private void CargarWebServices() {
        progreso= new ProgressDialog(this);
        progreso.setMessage("CARGANDO...");
        progreso.show();

        String url="http://192.168.1.20/indeportes/registro.php?nombre="+TextNombre.getText().toString()+
                "&correo="+TextEmail.getText().toString();

        url=url.replace(" ","%20");

        StringRequest stringRequest= new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "OPERACION EXITOSA", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                progreso.hide();
                TextNombre.setText("");
                TextEmail.setText("");
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue= Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);

    }
```