# insertar varios registros a la vez en mysql desde android studio

Tags: php, sql, android-studio, phpmyadmin

Hola a toda la comunidad, por favor su apoyo con el siguiente caso, tengo que enviar los siguientes registros a través de un app a una tabla en phpMyAdmin:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del activity que utilizo para ingresar los registros:

```
package com.example.appgloria;

public class Registro extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registro);

    final EditText clienteT          = EditText)findViewById(R.id.clienteRegistro);
    final EditText direccionT        = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.direcionRegistro);
    final TextView productoT         = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.producto1);
    final EditText compraT           = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETPC);
    final EditText ventaT            = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.ETPV);
    Button btnRegistro = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegistro);

    btnRegistro.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        //esto va en registro request
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final  String cliente       = clienteT.getText().toString();
            final  String direccion     = direccionT.getText().toString();
            final  String producto      = productoT.getText().toString();
            final  String compra        = compraT.getText().toString();
            final  String venta         = ventaT.getText().toString();

            Response.Listener<String> respuesta = new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try{
                        JSONObject jsonrespuesta = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean ok = jsonrespuesta.getBoolean("success");
                        if(ok == true){
                            Intent i = new Intent(Registro.this,Final.class);
                            Registro.this.startActivity(i);
                            Registro.this.finish();
                        }else{
                            AlertDialog.Builder alerta = new AlertDialog.Builder(Registro.this);
                            alerta.setMessage("Fallo en el registro")
                                    .setNegativeButton("Reintentar",null)
                                    .create()
                                    .show();
                        }
                    }catch (JSONException e){
                        e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
            };

            RegistroRequest r = new RegistroRequest(cliente,direccion,producto,compra,venta,respuesta);
            RequestQueue cola = Volley.newRequestQueue(Registro.this);
            cola.add(r);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Y este es el código del Activity que envía la información:

```
package com.example.appgloria;

public class Bienvenido extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bienvenido);

    final TextView mensaje = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mensaje);

    Intent i = this.getIntent();
    String nombre = i.getStringExtra("nombre");
    int edad = i.getIntExtra("edad",-1);
    mensaje.setText(mensaje.getText()+" "+nombre+" Su edad:"+edad+"");
}

//Metodo para para pasar de bienvenido a registro
public void levantamiento_de_precios(View view){
    Intent levantamiento_de_precios = new Intent(this,Registro.class);
    startActivity(levantamiento_de_precios);
}

//Metodo para para pasar de bienvenido a asistencia
public void asistencia(View view){
    Intent asistencia = new Intent(this,Asistencia.class);
    startActivity(asistencia);
}

//Metodo para para pasar de bienvenido a visitas
public void visitas(View view){
    Intent visitas = new Intent(this,Visitas.class);
    startActivity(visitas);
}
}
```

A continuación el archivo php que utilizo para insertar los datos a la tabla que se encuentra en phpMyAdmin:

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "id9055504_root", "root123", "id9055504_bdgloria");

$cliente        = $_POST["cliente"];
$direccion      = $_POST["direccion"];
$producto       = $_POST["producto"];
$compra         = $_POST["compra"];
$venta          = $_POST["venta"];
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO precios (cliente, direccion, producto, compra, venta) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sssss", $cliente, $direccion, $producto, $compra, $venta);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Por favor me podrían enseñar que debo de modificar en mis códigos para poder insertar **todos los registros al mismo tiempo**. Les estoy muy agradecido de antemano. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Actualmente, ¿Que hace tu código? ¿Se conecta adecuadamente?. Mira este enlace: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php  Como primera idea me aseguraría que la conexión es válida.

Comment: Tienes que pasar los datos al servidor mediante el método `getHeaders()`, y luego recuperarlos en el servidor e insertarlos. O sea, tu petición `Volley` debe tener también algo parecido a esto: `@Override
        public Map getHeaders() {
            HashMap headers = new HashMap();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
            headers.put("Nombre", "Pedro");
            headers.put("Apellido", "García");
            return headers;
        }` Luego en el servidor muchas veces los datos no pueden recuperarse con un simple `$_POST` como se hace...

Comment: ... habitualmente, sino que tienes que recurrir a `apache_request_headers()`. [En esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/252342/29967) yo intenté explicarlo con algunos detalles. Creo que te podría servir para implementar tu código y si tienes problemas concretos entonces puedes preguntar.

Comment: Ramon, actualmente mi código si se conecta adecuadamente, todo lo escribo en la aplicación y se envía a la tabla que tengo creada en phpMyAdmin, pero solo hago el envío de un solo registro, lo que yo deseo hacer es el envío simultaneo de registros de la tabla excel que muestro.

Comment: Ramon y A.cedano, voy a revisar las indicaciones que me han brindado y les comento como me fue, muchas gracias.