# Java.net.ConnectException: Failed to conect to /127.0.0.1:443 Error en Aplicacion Android

Tags: android-studio

estoy programando una app en Android Studio la cual contiene un Login que se conecta a una base de datos en XAMPP a través de PHP, ya probé la parte de PHP y trabaja bien, pero al momento de querer conectarme al archivo de validar usuario me suelta el error del titulo, he buscado y me di cuenta que el error esta en la ip que le puse pero ya probé con otra ip y aun no se enlaza, la pregunta sería que ip le tengo que poner y en caso de no ser la ip, en donde esta el error, adjunto la clase del Login

```
    public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText txtCorreoTel, txtContrasenia;
    Button btnIniciarSesion;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    txtCorreoTel = findViewById(R.id.txtCorreoTelefono);
    txtContrasenia = findViewById(R.id.txtContrasenia);
    btnIniciarSesion = findViewById(R.id.btnIniciarSesion);



    btnIniciarSesion.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            validarUsuario("http://127.0.0.1/servicios/validar_usuario.php");
        }
    });
}




private void validarUsuario(String URL){
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            if (!response.isEmpty()){
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Usuario o Contraseña incorrecta", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            /*String message = null;
            if (error instanceof NetworkError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (error instanceof ServerError) {
                message = "The server could not be found. Please try again after some time!!";
            } else if (error instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (error instanceof ParseError) {
                message = "Parsing error! Please try again after some time!!";
            } else if (error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                message = "Cannot connect to Internet...Please check your connection!";
            } else if (error instanceof TimeoutError) {
                message = "Connection TimeOut! Please check your internet connection.";
            }
            Toast.makeText(Login.this,message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*/
        }

    }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String,String> parametros = new HashMap<String, String>();
            parametros.put("correo", txtCorreoTel.getText().toString());
            parametros.put("contrasenia", txtContrasenia.getText().toString());
            return parametros;
        }
    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
}
```

Comment: La URL tendrías que apuntar a tu equipo, no a localhost, generalmente son direcciones del tipo `192.168....` y habría quizá que incluir el puerto del servidor que suele ser `8080`, revisa la forma de URL que se usa en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/252293/29967) cuidando de poner la dirección IP correcta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La razòn por la cual obtienes el error:

> Java.net.ConnectException: Failed to conect to /127.0.0.1:443

Se debe a que desde un dispositivo Android no podras alcanzar la direccion http://127.0.0.1/ , esta direcciòn es de tu localhost de tu servidor o pc

```
 validarUsuario("http://127.0.0.1/servicios/validar_usuario.php");
```

Asegura que puedas publicar y consultar desde internet el archivo `servicios/validar_usuario.php`

Comment: Gracias, tienes razón el problema estaba en que usaba la ip local de la computadora y tenia que usar la de LAN

Comment: Y no hiciste una configuración adicional?, tengo el mismo problema pero no se solucion usando la ip LAN.

Comment: Si deseas usar la IP de la LAN, debes asegurar que tu página es visible usando esta IP , y que te encuentres conectado a la misma red.

Comment: Y si no es visible, que necesito hacer?, ya investigue e hice configuraciones pero no se logra ver